# Why can I access my database only via SSH tunnelling?

Tags: networking, vpn, docker, database

**I made a server from a Raspberry Pi (RPI) for my private tasks.** I run there a couple of applications/services, such as web analytics dashboard (dash, Python), Apache Airflow server, databases etc. All of my applications/services run in separate Docker containers.

**Lately I decided to use VPN in order to improve my network security and I wanted my RPI to be reachable from any other place, not only from my local network.** Generally speaking, it works great, but there's one "problem" with my PostgreSQL database.

**I can easily access all of the applications/services, but in order to access the PostgreSQL database, I have to use SSH Tunneling.** The strange thing is that I don't have to use SSH Tunneling to acces the database when I DON'T USE VPN - when I use my local network connection, then I only need my RPI IP address, port, database username and password.

**Do you have any ideas what the "problem" is?** I understand that the above situation may be desirable from a security perspective and therefore this shouldn't be considered a problem, but still I would like to understand how it works.

If it makes a difference, **NordVPN is my VPN provider.**

Comment: you've probably set your Pi to route **all** traffic through the VPN - don't know nordvpn at all, but hopefully that info is enough for you to correct the settings